# Prevent window scroll events with chrome extension

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to come up with a concept to prevent window scroll events when firing scrollTop function from the chrome extension script injection.

I'm building a simple screenshot extension to capture full page images. The extension basically scrolls through the whole page, takes all the screenshots needed and then combine them. Problem is that there are some position fixed elements that appears on every print taken, which is not desirable.

I've manage to fix this by looping through the dom and looking for elements with position fixed attribute set by default in css. It works, but if an element gets position fixed through a script, e.g., when a scroll event happens a div appears, I then can't remove it.

Any advice in how to accomplish this?

Cheers!

Comment: DOM `scroll` event is [not cancelable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/scroll) so I would try [pausing all js](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Debugger/#method-pause) in that tab via chrome.debugger API. It may pause your content script as well though... BTW using chrome.debugger you [can screenshot pages](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-captureScreenshot) of up to 16384 px tall.

Comment: @wOxxOm captureScreenshot does not seem to be taking the full page height, but instead capturing only the view portion.